# What's the proper way to test if a Postgresql array field is either null or empty

Tags: comparison, postgresql, function, arrays, null

I have a table defined with an integer_array field. It contains the following data:

```
 id | black_list 
----+------------
  4 |            
  5 |            
  8 |            
 12 |            
  6 |            
  7 |            
 10 | {5}        
 13 | {5}        
  3 | {}         
  9 | {3}        
 11 | {}         
 14 | {}         
  1 | {}         
  2 | {}         
 15 | {}         
 16 | {}         
 17 | {}         
(17 rows)
```

I need to write a query to see if the array field is empty - NULL or otherwise. The trouble is that the `{}` values are not null, nor do they return any length from the ARRAY_LENGTH function. None of the other array functions listed at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-array.html seem to be what I need either. I've found that I can write `ARRAY_LENGTH(0 || black_list)` to get all of them to return a length of 1 or more, but that seems like a nasty hack. What's the proper way to test this?

Bonus question: What exactly is `{}` representative of? I've been unable to write a select statement that will return that value. `ARRAY[]` throws an error, `ARRAY[""]` returns `{""}`, `ARRAY[NULL]` returns `{NULL}`, etc.

Comment: I realize that I could just write the inverse and test to see if the length is greater than 0, but I'd like to know why there doesn't seem to be a way to test it this way;

Comment: {} seems to represent an empty array, which would explain both the value being NOT NULL and ARRAY_LENGTH({}) not returning anything -- though I'd expect it to return 0 on {}, perhaps that's a PostgreSQL peculiarity with which I'm unfamiliar. Is there a reason you can't just test the return value of ARRAY_LENGTH, as e.g. 'SELECT id FROM table WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(black_list) IS NULL OR ARRAY_LENGTH(black_list) < 1'? Assuming ARRAY_LENGTH() doesn't lose its mind on empty values such as that for id=12 in the example above, it seems like that'd do the trick.

Comment: (I don't have a Postgre server handy at the moment to test against, hence the untested query in my previous comment. Sorry if I've sent you down a blind alley.)

Comment: Yeah, actually `ARRAY_LENGTH(provider_black_list, 1) IS NULL` works pretty well. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Sure thing! I'll make an answer out of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{}` seems to represent an empty array, which would explain both the value being `NOT NULL` and `ARRAY_LENGTH({})` not returning anything – though I'd expect it to return 0 on `{}`, perhaps that's a PostgreSQL peculiarity with which I'm unfamiliar.

Is there a reason you can't just test the return value of `ARRAY_LENGTH`, as e.g.

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(black_list, 1) IS NULL OR ARRAY_LENGTH(black_list, 1) < 1
```

Assuming `ARRAY_LENGTH()` doesn't lose its mind on empty values such as that for `id=12` in the example above, it seems like that'd do the trick.

Comment: It works! Not at all how I'd expect to have to do so, put it simplified my previous query and reads well.

Comment: BTW - `ARRAY_LENGTH(black_list, 1) IS NULL` tests correctly against both empty `{}` values as well as `NULL` values, so no need to test for `< 1` in addition.

Comment: I HAD to use 'IS NULL' like in the answer. When I tried '= NULL' it does not work. Strange but your method works :)

Comment: @itsols That's because testing anything including NULL for equality against NULL returns NULL. Why this should be, I have no idea, but it's worth knowing nonetheless.